# Apply Twitter Bootstrap Validation Style and Message to ASP.NET MVC validation

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

How can I integrate ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive validation and Twitter Bootstrap? I want to have all those validation **messages** and **styles** appropriately.

Comment: May be related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065442/integrating-twitter-bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-3-forms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest to include Bootstrapper in less format and do the same thing as Iridio suggested but in .less.
That way you could have something like:

```
.validation-summary-errors
{
    .alert();
    .alert-error();
}
.field-validation-error 
{
    .label();
    .label-important();
}
```

so when bootstrapper will change you'll pick up the changes automatically.
Regular styles that handle visibility from MVC default `Site.css` will stay in place and handle visibility.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use simply a separate file for something small like this. I agree with [this article](http://daneden.me/2012/05/preprocessors/), but as usual I think it's matter of taste

Comment: @Shaddix how can I do that? I have my Bootstrap.css file, And I've just added an Alerts.less file with what you posted. But it doesn't seem to work that way. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You can achieve this without using LESS, or copy-pasting CSS styles or using JavaScript. Please see the answer I have added.

Comment: Perfect - works great for me even in Bootstrap 3 except that ```alert-error()``` needs to be ```alert-danger()``` and ```label-important()``` needs to be ```label-warning()```.

Answer (score 39):

A nice way of handling this if you're using Bootstrap 2 is...

Add this to your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    }
});

$(function () {

    $("span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error").addClass('help-inline');
    $("div.control-group").has("span.field-validation-error").addClass('error');
    $("div.validation-summary-errors").has("li:visible").addClass("alert alert-block alert-error");

});

</script>
```

These are the posts where I found the code pieces above:

[Integrating Bootstrap Error styling with MVC’s Unobtrusive Error Validation](http://www.braindonor.net/blog/integrating-bootstrap-error-styling-with-mvcs-unobtrusive-error-validation)

[Twitter Bootstrap validation styles with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2013/01/23/twitter-bootstrap-validation-styles-with-asp-net-mvc)

[MVC Twitter Bootstrap unobtrusive error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18135224/114029)

---

**UPDATE**

Right now I needed to do the same when using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-states). Here's the modifications necessary since the class names changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
        {
            if (element.type === 'radio')
            {
                this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            } else
            {
                $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
        {
            if (element.type === 'radio')
            {
                this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
            } else
            {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            }
        }
    });

$(function () {

    $("span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error").addClass('help-block');
    $("div.form-group").has("span.field-validation-error").addClass('has-error');
    $("div.validation-summary-errors").has("li:visible").addClass("alert alert-block alert-danger");

});

</script>
```

Comment: also wanted to thank you for the 3.0 version.  saved me some time. ;)

Comment: @NateJackson here to give back! Glad it's being helpful. :)

Comment: Is there a recommended way for Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 25):

Copy the css of the validators in your css file and change the color accordinlgly.
Something like this should do

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    /*
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
    */
    color: #b94a48;
    border-color: #b94a48;
}

.input-validation-error:focus {
  border-color: #953b39;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #d59392;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #d59392;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #d59392;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Definitely prefer the CSS solution over the JS one for my needs (and not using LESS yet) - thanks!

Comment: If your like me and put the user auth fields in the header on the opposing side of the logo. In .field-validation-error you can add position:absolute and a background-color. It won't effect the look of the header.

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use css !important and call it a day:

```
/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00 !important;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00 !important;
    background-color: #fee !important;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

On Bootstrap ***3*** you have to add:

```
.validation-summary-errors
{
    .alert();
    .alert-danger();
}
.field-validation-error 
{
    .label();
    .label-danger();
}
```

you'll see something like that:

[image: Validation errors demo]

Comment: Is that part of css? Resharper complains for me that () after alert is an unexpected token.

Comment: It's LESS. You'd have to copy the styles that those alert/alert-danger/label/label-danger cover if you wanted to do this in pure CSS.

Comment: Incidentally this looks quite neat. Doesn't apply `has-error` to the whole control-group, so the label isn't coloured / doesn't use default bootstrap validation styling. Also doesn't cover the field itself but that's pretty trivial as the field will have a class on it anyway.

Comment: That looks neat indeed. I'll use the idea - thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

For the `ValidationSummary`, you can use the overload that allows you to specify `htmlAttributes`. This allows you to set it to use the Twitter Bootstrap alert css styles.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(string.Empty, new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
```

A similar overload exists for the `ValidationMessage` and `ValidationMessageFor` helper methods.

Comment: It doesn't work if you have the case when validation message split in 2 lines

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  No hacks required.

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate MVC3 validation with Bootstrap framework by adding the following javascript to your page (View)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
/* Bootstrap Fix */
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest("div.control-group").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest("div.control-group").removeClass("error");
    }
});
var current_div;
$(".editor-label, .editor-field").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("editor-label")) {
        current_div = $('<div class="control-group"></div>').insertBefore(this);
    }
    current_div.append(this);
});
$(".editor-label").each(function () {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
$(".editor-field").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("controls");
    $(this).removeClass("editor-field");
});
$("label").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("control-label");
});
$("span.field-validation-valid, span.field-validation-error").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("help-inline");
});
$("form").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-horizontal");
    $(this).find("div.control-group").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("span.field-validation-error").length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Besides, on the Views (for example "Create.cshtml") make sure that the fields in the form are formatted as the following...

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Name)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using Bootstrap 3, the css classes have changed and the solutions above need modifications to work with Bootstrap 3. I have used the following with success with MVC 4 and Bootstrap 3. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320483/validation-mvc4-razor-and-bootstrap/20341881#20341881) SO thread for more:

```
$(function () {
 // any validation summary items should be encapsulated by a class alert and alert-danger
    $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('alert');
        $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
    });

    // update validation fields on submission of form
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-error');
                    $(this).addClass('has-success');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-success');
                    $(this).addClass('has-error');
                }
            });
            $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('alert-danger') == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert');
                    $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // check each form-group for errors on ready
    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});

var page = function () {
    //Update the validator
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        }
    });
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a few classes to your Site.css file:

```
/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}

select.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

FYI: http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/form-validation-formatting-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

This will convert `ValidationSummary()` to a boostrap alert.  You can include a little script to remove unnecessary classes and give a highlight to fields with problems.

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())) {
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
      <h4>Validation Errors</h4>
      @Html.ValidationSummary()
   </div>
}

<script>
$(".validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-errors");
$(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error").parent().addClass("has-error");
</script>
```

See more information at http://chadkuehn.com/convert-razor-validation-summary-into-bootstrap-alert/

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat solution that gives you more control over how the ValidationSummary renders errors to the view. The Unordered List it produced did not look right inside the alert. Therefore, I simply looped through the errors and rendered them how I wanted - using paragraphs in this case. For example:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        @foreach (var modelError in Html.ViewData.ModelState.SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors))
        {
            <p>@modelError.ErrorMessage</p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Which results in a neat Validation Summary Alert:
[image]

Comment: This approach only works with server-side validation, not client-side validation since the if statement can't be evaluated on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
$(function () {
    // any validation summary items should be encapsulated by a class alert and alert-danger
    $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('alert');
        $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
    });

    // update validation fields on submission of form
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-error');
                    $(this).addClass('has-success');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('div.control-group').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                    $(this).removeClass('has-success');
                    $(this).addClass('has-error');
                }
            });
            $('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('alert-danger') == false) {
                    $(this).addClass('alert');
                    $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // check each form-group for errors on ready
    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
});

var page = function () {
    //Update the validator
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
        }
    });
}();
```

Taken from http://www.benripley.com/development/javascript/asp-mvc-4-validation-with-bootstrap-3.