# Bootstrap with jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add validation to my form with jQuery Validation Plugin, but I'm having a problem where the plugin puts the error messages when I'm using input groups.

[image: the problem]

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

**My code:** http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/4/

Comment: Inherited an app w/ Bootstrap 3, laughed that I'd found this and had bookmarked it years ago when I last inherited an app with Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

for total compatibility with twitter bootstrap 3, I need to override some plugins methods:

```
// override jquery validate plugin defaults
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

See Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mapb_1990/hTPY7/7/

Comment: WOrks great, just wanted to mention to add $(element).removeClass(errorClass); to unhighlight and $(element).addClass(errorClass); to highlight if you want success to not use the bootstrap help-block class

Comment: This works well, except for one thing: Testing against jQuery Validate 1.11.1 and calling `resetForm()` on a form's validator will not call `unhighlight` on invalid elements, making it necessary to remove the `has-error` class by hand when resetting a form. What I do is to call the following function instead of calling the validator's `resetForm()` directly: `function resetForm(form_id) { $(form_id).find(".form-group").removeClass("has-error"); $(form_id).data('validator').resetForm(); }`

Comment: If you have radio buttons like Bootstrap suggests (radio inputs placed inside label tags), you'll want to add something like this to that if block: `else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') { error.insertBefore(element.parent().parent()); }`

Answer (score 88):

For full compatibility with Bootstrap 3 I added support for **input-group**, **radio** and **checkbox**, that was missing in the other solutions.

**Update 10/20/2017**: Inspected suggestions of the other answers and added additional support for special markup of **radio-inline**, better error placement for a group of radios or checkboxes and added support for a custom **.novalidation** class to prevent validation of controls. Hope this helps and thanks for the suggestions.

After including the validation plugin add the following call:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // Only validation controls
        if (!$(element).hasClass('novalidation')) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // Only validation controls
        if (!$(element).hasClass('novalidation')) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio' && element.parent('.radio-inline').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

This works for all Bootstrap 3 form classes. If you use a horizontal form you have to use the following markup. This ensures that the **help-block** text respects the validation states ("has-error", ...) of the **form-group**.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label id="LabelConfirm" for="CheckBoxConfirm">
                <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxConfirm" id="CheckBoxConfirm" required="required" />
                I have read all the information 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tweaked `errorClass: "help-block error-help-block"`.  I was already using .help-block for regular help information, and this was overwriting it with form validation messages.  Adding a second class made it unique and so now it appends rather than overwrites my "real" help message.

Comment: Hilight method not called

Comment: Hello Vlado, could you give some more information why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: For a group of radio buttons, this will add the error message below the first option which looks weird. You likely want to tweak this to treat radio buttons differently.

Comment: I had to add `width: 100%;` to my checkbox label for this to work, the message was being placed right next to it

Answer (score 23):

I use forms designed only  with Twitter Bootstrap 3. I set defaults functions for validor and run only validate method with rules. I use Icons from FontAweSome, but you can use Glyphicons as in doc example.

[image]

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
            $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('i.fa').remove();
            $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg form-control-feedback"></i>');
        }
    }
});
```

Done. After run validate function:

```
$("#default-register-user").validate({
    rules: {
        'login': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 20
        },
        'email': {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 100
        },
        'password': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 25
        },
        'confirmpassword': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 25,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dark_diesel/gzmwtvh3/)

Comment: Would be great to have a JSFiddle for this

Comment: Could you post the HTML you used for the screenshot, please?  The fiddle example doesn't have the red-styled error message nor the icons. Thanks!

Comment: Christopher Francisco, i updated JSFiddle example and add font awesome css.

Comment: Hi great solution! How would you edit this so that only those fields that have rules show success or failure messages? Right your code makes all fields display the css, regardless if there are rules or not

Comment: The solution is to add: 'ignore: ".ignore, :hidden"' right above the rules. Then just add an 'ignore' class to all fields you don't want validated

Comment: The email validation isn't working properly. You can enter something like asga@da - yes without a domain ending and it's being accepted. This is because the input target 'email' is set in quotation marks - they have to be left out - then it works properly.

Answer (score 10):

Adding onto Miguel Borges answer above you can give the user that green success feedback by adding the following line to in the highlight/unhighlight code block.

```
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

this is the solution you need, you can use the `errorPlacement` method to override where to put the error message

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter('.form-group'); //So i putted it after the .form-group so it will not include to your append/prepend group.
    }, 
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

it's works for me like magic.
Cheers

Comment: ```error.insertAfter('.form-group');``` put errors in all .form-group. but it showed me the idea. thank you

Answer (score 7):

for bootstrap 4 this work with me good

```
    $.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find(".form-control:first").addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find(".form-control:first").removeClass('is-invalid');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find(".form-control:first").addClass('is-valid');

    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

hope it will help !

Comment: This works out of the box very well! Only thing I added was `validClass: 'valid-feedback'`

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I use when adding validation to form:

```
// Adding validation to form.
        $(form).validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                },
                server: {
                    ipAddress: true,
                    required: true
                }   
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            },
            success: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            },
            errorClass: 'help-block'
        });
```

This worked for me for Bootstrap 3 styling when using the jquery validation library.

Answer (score 3):

I used this for radio's:

```
    if (element.prop("type") === "checkbox" || element.prop("type") === "radio") {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
    }
    else if (element.parent(".input-group").length) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
    else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
```

this way the error is displayed under last radio option.

Comment: Brilliantly simple answer, thanks - just slotted the extra type clause into my existing errorPlacement logic

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is for Bootstrap 3, but as some Bootstrap 4 related question are redirected to this one as duplicates, here's the snippet Bootstrap 4-compatible:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
    },
    errorElement: 'small',
    errorClass: 'form-control-feedback d-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else if(element.prop('type') === 'checkbox') {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().parent());
        } else if(element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
});
```

The few differences are:

- The use of class `has-danger` instead of `has-error`
- Better error positioning radios and checkboxes

Comment: Bootstrap 4 no longer have the `.has-*` classes. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#forms-1

Answer (score 2):

For the bootstrap 4 beta were some big changes between the alpha and beta versions of bootstrap (and also bootstrap 3), esp. in regards to form validation.

First, to place the icons correctly you'll need to add styling which equates to what was in bootstrap 3 and no longer in bootstrap 4 beta...here's what I'm using

```
.fa.valid-feedback,
.fa.invalid-feedback {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.fa.valid-feedback {
    margin-top: -28px;
}
```

The classes have also changed as the beta uses the 'state' of the control rather than classes which your posted code doesn't reflect, so your above code may not work. Anyway, you'll need to add 'was-validated' class to the form either in the success or highlight/unhighlight callbacks

```
$(element).closest('form').addClass('was-validated');
```

I would also recommend using the new element and classes for form control help text

```
errorElement: 'small',
errorClass: 'form-text invalid-feedback',
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes up the fields

```
 $("#form_questionario").validate({
                debug: false,
                errorElement: "span",
                errorClass: "help-block",
                highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.parent('.input-group').length || element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                        error.insertBefore(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                // Specify the validation rules
                rules: {
                        'campo1[]': 'required',
                        'campo2[]': 'required',
                        'campo3[]': 'required',
                        'campo4[]': 'required',
                        'campo5[]': 'required'
                        },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

add radio-inline fix to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754780/966181

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else if (element.parent('.radio-inline').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's simple, is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DARK_DIESEL's answer worked great for me; here's the code for anyone who wants the equivalent using glyphicons:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-feedback').addClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
            $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error has-feedback').addClass('has-success has-feedback');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span.glyphicon').remove();
            $(element).closest('.form-group').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sample code. Using the Jquery validation plugin and additional methods.
This is the working code for my project. Hope this helps you

```js
//jquery validation booking page
 
 // Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='book']").validate({
   //on key up validation
   onkeyup: function(element) {
      $(element).valid(); 
    },  
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      fname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      lname:{
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
        },
      email: {
        required: true,
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      fname: {
      required:"Please enter your firstname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
      lname: {
      required:"Please enter your lastname",
      lettersonly:"Letters allowed only"
      },
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="design/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="design/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form name="book" id="book" action="" method="post">

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <label class="" for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <label class="" for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control datepicker px-2" placeholder="Date of visit">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="" for="treatment">Service You Want</label>
            <select name="treatment" id="treatment" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Hair Cut</option>
                <option value="">Hair Coloring</option>
                <option value="">Perms and Curls</option>
                <option value="">Hair Conditioning</option>
                <option value="">Manicure</option>
                <option value="">Pedicure</option>
                <option value="">Nails Extension</option>
                <option value="">Nail Design</option>
                <option value="">Waxing Eyebrows</option>
                <option value="">Waxing Hands/Legs</option>
                <option value="">Full Face Waxing</option>
                <option value="">Full Body/Body Parts Wax</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="" for="note">Notes</label>
            <textarea name="note" id="note" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your notes or questions here..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <center><input type="submit" value="Book Now" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"></center>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is placing an error container outside of your form group ahead of time.  The validator will then use it if necessary.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="new-task-due-date">When is the task due?</label>
  <div class="input-group date datepicker">
    <input type="text" id="new-task-due-date" class="required form-control date" name="dueDate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>                          
  </div>
  <label for="new-task-due-date" class="has-error control-label" style="display: none;"></label>
</div>
```