# An error style for the whole form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show the errors related not only to a particular input (field) of the form but to the whole form, for example, I might show the list of them above the form.

What I found is http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18754780/643500

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb, isn't there a standard way?

Comment: To be honest I do not know exactly what you have implemented.  You have to show the implementation and a specific question about a specific problem.  What's your server-side or is it all client-side validation?

Comment: It's easy with a server-side language like PHP (after a page refresh, of course).