# Bootstrap 3 validation states with input groups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do add bootstrap 3 validation states to input groups. The state seems to only apply to the input part of the group.

EDIT 10/02/2014: To clarify, I'm using an input group with a button:

```
<div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/112305

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: That is not the same question - that is jquery (which I'm not using at all)

Comment: May you find some soution on that question that is using group input.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to place the actual input in its own block. Try the following:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div style="position:relative"><!-- sub container for the input and validation state -->
            <input name="emailAddress" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"><!----></span>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="button-send" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="input-group">` is not closed

Comment: indeed it wasn't. It's in the markup but for some reason it wasn't showing up. I've edited and fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a `form-group` and apply the validation state class to the form-group..

```
<div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">00</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/111979

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better but I'm using an input group with a textbox and a button. I've updated my question above

Comment: How would one go about applying the validation class to `form-group`?  A lot of use HtmlHelpers present in ASP.NET MVC, and have no control over where that class gets applied!