# Bootstrap 3 validation using bootstrapValidator with input-group not display error properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I am using Bootstrap 3 and for validation using bootstrapValidator(https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator). It is dislaying error message proplerly for input field but not working with
input-group(https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/issues/126)

As shown in above github link, same issue occur to me and here is the solution for jquery form validator ,not for bootstrapvalidator.

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

You can check code here:

```
[Code][1] http://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/LVqKEg
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI can you show me the put the code then it was easy to help you

Comment: I have updated above to get code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjMxRO

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645408/bootstrap-3-validation-states-with-input-groups