# Bootstrap 3 form using input-group-addon wrapping error labels with Jquery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 with a form-horizontal using form-group and input-group tags with Jquery-Validate.  When Jquery.Validate runs for errors, it appends a label error control within the input-group.

The issue is that input-group-addon wraps to the next line underneath the form field when the label error control is added by Jquery Validate.
[image: Jquery Validate error wrapping input-group-addon]

VIEW:
http://www.bootply.com/114554

How do I get the label error to stay under the form control and **not** wrap the input-group-addon to the next line?

Yes, I am aware of this solution - works great, but still doesn't line up the error label for form-horizontal:
[Bootstrap 3 with jQuery Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: could you not just use the suggestion, then add an offset class to error-class? eg errorClass: 'help-block col-md-offset-2',

Answer (score 6):

Solved it another way:
http://www.bootply.com/2liEuyqrAb

Had to move the label outside of the input-group.  Once doing that, did the expected behavior: form label to left, field to right, and error below field.

Comment: As the error label is added dynamically by the jQuery Validate plugin, this solution does not help.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to solve your problem should be to put your error label with absolute position property in css.
In your example here's the result :

```
.text-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
    left: 0px;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I give a solution to this question for another user, its the same problem.

You can find it here. [Bootstrap-3: Input Group-Addon STRETCHES with jQuery Validation messages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788150/bootstrap-3-input-group-addon-stretches-with-jquery-validation-messages/43790627?noredirect=1#comment74624998_43790627)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting issue with `input-group`, try the css fix or below code.

```
  $('.your-form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
      if(element.parent().hasClass('input-group')){
        error.insertAfter( element.parent() );
      }else{
        error.insertAfter( element );
      }
    }
  });
```