# Bootstrap button add-on interferes with validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

How to resolve this issue where there is an add-on which overlaps with the cross?

Comment: Do you want to move the cross over to the left? Use padding or margin.  Do you want to hide it? Use display: none; Post your code if you would like better help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you will need to use the [ErrorPlacement](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) function to control where errors are placed with your inputs. This question (see the accepted answer) might be helpful: [Bootstrap 3 with jQuery Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-3-with-jquery-validation-plugin)