# JQuery Validate Form Inputs & Highlight Labels with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate

> I have read I have read [Bootstrap with jQuery Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754020/bootstrap-with-jquery-validation-plugin)
>   and it's helpful, but it's Bootstrap 3, **not** Bootstrap 4..

I'm using [JQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) with **Bootstrap 4**, but can't seem to get the label **and** input field to [highlight](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) red when it's invalid.

I thought the `valid` and `invalid` input classes were default in BS, [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/?#validation)? Maybe i'm using them incorrectly.

My code is below, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/futv5L7d/).

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    },
  });
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These classes have changed in [the most recent release](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/?#server-side). `valid` was renamed to `is-valid` and `invalid` is `is-invalid`.

Also, they need to be applied to inputs, not input group wrappers.

**Edit:**

You need to reorder the input and label if you want both to be highlighted.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
    },
  });
})
```

```css
.reversed{padding: 3rem 0 0 0;}
.reversed .control-label{margin: -4.5rem 0 0 0; float: left;}

input.is-valid ~ label{color: green;}
input.is-invalid ~ label{color: red;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group reversed"><!-- added reversed class -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Email address</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek yeah, just added an example.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek if you want to do that, you could write more `javascript` or you can do it in `css`. There's no built-in method within bootstrap to highlight the label as well.